# Wait a closure to complete in the middle of a function chaining in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, closures, chaining

I was wondering whether I can wait for a closure to end in function chaining before the code runs towards the next function.

For example:

```
SomeSingletonClass.sharedInstance.bFunction()
```

And if it's the first call of the sharedInstance, I'd like bFunction() to wait until a closure* in the init() of SingletonClass ends.
Is it possible somehow without blocking the UI?

*This closure may show a Grant Access Authorisation Alert, and the bFunction() should wait the reaction of the user to this alert (or may not even call bFunction at all, depending on the answer of the user).

Thanks for any kind of advice in advanced.

## UPDATE

So as GoZoner suggested, I tried to block the execution in the `init()` method with `dispatch_semaphore_create() / signal() / wait()`, but in this case the application is blocked and can't show the AlertView.

Answer (score 1):

The `init()` method for your `SomeSingletonClass` will need to block its execution until the 'Grant Access Authorization Alert' completes.  Upon completion, the `init()` method resumes, the `sharedInstance` property returns and the `bFunction()` method is applied to the returned instance.

There are a number of ways to block the execution; what you use will depend on multiprocessing details of your application.

Comment: So, should I just simply block the main thread? Is it a good idea?
I may have some network requests (which started earlier) meanwhile displaying popup. Will the blocking of the execution affect these request (I mean, could it cause Request Timeout for example?).
Or I should execute the whole line of code on another thread?

Comment: If you must call `bFunction()` chained as you've shown, the you do need to block whatever thread `init()` is called on.  The other option is to use callbacks on your 'Alert' (or other UI actions).

Answer (score 1):

You could post an `NSNotification` from the Closure `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("weirdKeyName", object: nil)`

And listen to that notification and call your alert or whatever you need to do when the Closure code has been executed as soon as the notification arrives: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "alertFunction", name: "weirdKeyName, object: nil)`

```
alertFunction() {
  ...
}
```

Waiting for the NSNotification to trigger your alert will not cause your application to block and wait for the closure to complete.

Also if you desire so, you could send the notification to the background thread with `NSNotificationQueue`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your code

```
SomeSingletonClass.sharedInstance.bFunction()
```

Might be able to live in a thread other than the main thread?

That way the sharedInstance function (which initialises a `SomeSingletonClass`) can request the main thread asynchronously create an initialised value, and semaphore wait on it's completion?

That way, you don't block the main thread.